# Replace "//" with "/* */" in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace, str-replace

I'm working in a code to minify html/css/js but i got a problem.

I need to replace // with /* and */.

Example:

```
$(funcion(){
// Do something
});
```

Replace to:

```
$(funcion(){
/* Do something */
});
```

How do that?

Comment: if you're minifying code, you should remove comments anyway

Comment: Yes to @enigma, and you're adding 2 to 3 bytes

Comment: Why *exactly* do you need to do this?  What problem are you *actually* trying to solve?

Comment: I will make the assumption that they have code that minifys but it doesn't recognize `//` as a comment.

Comment: You can use a regular express to identify // followed by anything to the end of the line. Then, replace what you found by adding /* and */ to it. This will break miserably if you have quoted strings with // in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, as was pointed out in the comments, if you're looking to reduce the size, comments should be stripped.

```
function convertComment(str){
   if(str.substring(0,2) === '//'){
       str = '/*' + str.substring(2) + ' */';
   } else {
       str = false;
   }
   return str;
}
```

Your example code looked like JQuery, so if you were looking for PHP, here is that version:

```
function convertComment($s){
   if(substr($s,0,2) == '//'){
       $s = '/*' . substr($s,2) . ' */';
   } else {
       $s = false;
   }
   return $s;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like PHP to me

Comment: Neither does OP's, it's JavaScript with JQuery. If he wanted PHP Code, he should have given an example in PHP.

Comment: OP is running PHP on a JS string, I think.

Comment: OP tries to minify JS in PHP...

Comment: There is no evidence in his post that he is doing this. He simply states, _working in a code to minify html/css/js_

Comment: Yes, no evidence in code or post of content but tagging is PHP related.

Comment: Agreed, and we both read into the question in different ways. Subject suggests OP wanted to do it in PHP, yet example code was JQuery. There is some vagueness to the post. This results in two answers that may be correct. Yours does do what is eluded to by OP as much as mine does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this regex:

```
/(?m)^\h*\/\/(.*)$/
```

then replace with

`/*$1*/`

to replace each line that starts with `//` or any amount of spaces before the `//`.

Regex101 Demo: https://regex101.com/r/oE0rY0/1

The `(?m)` enables the `m` modifier which makes `^` and `$` match each line rather than the whole string. The `\h*` is zero or more spaces. The `\/` is escaping the first `/` since that is the delimiter (could be any delimiter then wouldn't need to escape, http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php). Then the `.*` is every character until the end of the line `$`. The `()` captures the found value after the `//`.

PHP Usage:

```
$string = '//replace me please
dont touch http://www.google.com
or //this one
  //but this one do as well';
$regex = '/^\h*\/\/(.*)$/m';
echo preg_replace($regex, '/*$1*/', $string);
```

Output:

```
/*replace me please*/
dont touch http://www.google.com
or //this one
/*but this one do as well*/
```

PHP Demo: https://ideone.com/j7Xj4L

Comment: Thanks guys, but it don't solved my problem at all...
I explain better in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32899570/regex-get-line-but-not-if-start-with-http

Comment: Since it is the same question as this you should have updated this question with a more detailed explanation.