# Regex: Get // line but not if start with http://

Tags: php, regex

I need a Regex to get `//`, but if it starts with `http://` for it to do nothing.

Example:

```
<?php 
function lol(){
// blabalbal
} // catch'm all

echo 'http://link.com.br'; // this is a link.
```

Need to catch:

> // blabalbal line
>
> // catch'm all line (starting on "// catch")
>
> // this is a link (starting on "// this").

I was trying with variations of: '`/\/\/(.*)$`'

Comment: More detailed duplicate of [Replace "//" with "/\* \*/" in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32891256/replace-with-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can use this:

```
[^http:](//.*)
```

Discard strings with `http` and only capture strings that start with `//`

Comment: Actually, the [...] construct simply says that any of those characters -- not that string -- preceed the following segment. So possible something like this might actually work:
`[^:](//.*)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a negative lookbehind which php supports.

```
(?<!http:)(//.*)
```

This will only match `//` if it is not preceded by `http:`. You may be able to get away with just `:` depending on your needs.